# What does the Time Goddess look into when she wants to look into "memory of that time"?

Tags: half-minute-hero-the-second-coming

[image: Well then, would you like to check if you have memories from that time?]

Midway through Overture, the time goddess offers to check if I have a save game from Half Minute Hero: she said she'd be happy to bring equipment back from that game.. I do have one, but I kind of burned myself out in my attempts to get good times in it and I stopped playing it halfway through.

So... what does the time goddess look for in my past memories? Can I play more of Half Minute Hero and come back here to get the "bonuses" I risk missing out on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image] [image]

[Apparently](http://steamcommunity.com/app/240970/discussions/0/540738051101587843/), and I can confirm from what happened to me, all you seem to need is a save file with any amount of progress. This will give you the opportunity to buy the bent sword — a weapon that, for what is worth, is not on the list of [Half Minute Hero loot.](http://halfminutehero.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_items_and_equipment_in_Half-Minute_Hero)

Once the save file has been detected, the Time Goddess does not give you a chance to check again. I suppose that's because the game doesn't actually check how far you actually got in the game.

Be advised, however, that the bent sword gets "obsoleted" by the Bronze Axe available *in the very next quest* for 200 gold.